# HtmlAgilityPack Select individual elements from a list of divs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape using the HtmlAgilityPack child elements from a list of divs. The most parent Div is **//div[@class='cell in-area-cell middle-cell']** and if I simply iterate through the list I can display all the child content from each parent fine.

But I don't want to display all the content, I would like to pick certain div's, p's and a's from each of the children but the code below is only giving me a list of the first **//a[@class='listing-name']**. It gives me the correct number of lstRecords but they all have the same value.

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
public class TempSearch
{
    public string listing_name { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model List<tempsearch.Models.TempSearch>

@foreach (var ps in Model)
{
    <h4>@Html.Raw(ps.listing_name)</h4>
}
```

**Control:**

```
public ActionResult TempSearch()
{
    string html = Server.MapPath("~/Content/tempsearch.html");

    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument document = web.Load(html);

    List<TempSearch> lstRecords = new List<TempSearch>();

    foreach (HtmlNode node in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='cell in-area-cell middle-cell']"))
    {
        TempSearch tempSearch = new TempSearch();

        HtmlNode node2 = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//a[@class='listing-name']");

        tempSearch.listing_name += node2.InnerHtml.Trim();
        lstRecords.Add(tempSearch);

    }
    return View(lstRecords);
}
```

I guess it has something to do with the way i'm populating the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use XPath relative to element currently referenced by`node` variable, like this :

```
HtmlNode node2 = node.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='listing-name']");
```

Notice the `.` at the beginning of the XPath which indicate that the XPath is relative to *current context element*, and `SelectSingleNode()` method called on `node` variable to make `node` as the *current context element*. Otherwise, you'll always get the same element over and over on each iteration.

Comment: @Bojangles Any problem with this answer? Does it work for you?

Comment: wow! having a . before my xpath just saved me. wasted a bunch of time getting the first node of the page. didnt find this anywhere else when trying to find out how to query a node in a collection. thanks!!!