# HTML Agility Pack-Get always the first element details

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using **[HTML Agility](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)** Pack to fetch element's details from this url:[Link](http://www.trendyol.com/Butik/Liste/Kadin)

I'm using this code in C# (windows Form Application):

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    doc = webGet.Load("http://www.trendyol.com/Butik/Liste/Kadin");

    HtmlNodeCollection butiks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'butik')]");
    richTextBox1.Text = butiks.Count().ToString();

    if (butiks != null)
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode element in butiks)
        {
            var butikUrl = element.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='butik-large-image']/a").GetAttributeValue("href", null);
            var butikTitle = element.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='butik-large-image']/a").GetAttributeValue("title", null);
            var butikImg = element.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='butik-large-image']//a/img").GetAttributeValue("src", null);
            var butikEndTime = element.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='butik-name']/div[@class='butikTimeLine']/a/div[@class='timelineMain']/h1").GetAttributeValue("enddate", null);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("", butikUrl, butikTitle, butikImg, butikEndTime);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Null Obeject...!");
    }
```

This code always return me the element details. **Can you help?**

I also have used the following code but the following error occurs:

```
var butikUrl = element.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='butik-large-image']/a").GetAttributeValue("href", null);
                        var butikTitle = element.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='butik-large-image']/a").GetAttributeValue("title", null);
                        var butikImg = element.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='butik-large-image']//a/img").GetAttributeValue("src", null);
                        var butikEndTime = element.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='butik-name']/div[@class='butikTimeLine']/a/div[@class='timelineMain']/h1").GetAttributeValue("enddate", null);
```

This error is for `var butikUrl = element.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='butik-large-image']/a").GetAttributeValue("href", null);`

**Error:**    Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HtmlAgilityPack Select individual elements from a list of divs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960858/htmlagilitypack-select-individual-elements-from-a-list-of-divs)

Comment: @har07 I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath predicate to populate `butiks` variable seems too general. `contains(@class,'butik')` expression will also match `butik-large-image`, `butik-name`, etc. which don't have certain descendant element you're trying to access in the `foreach` loop body, that's possibly the cause of the exception. Try to use a more specific predicate, for example by matching `div` having `class` exactly equals `'butik large'` (XPath tested in Firefox's FirePath) :

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='butik large']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
HtmlNodeCollection butiks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'butik')]");
```

To

```
HtmlNodeCollection butiks = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'butik-large-image')]");
```

This should return the 20 stacked advertisement elements.

You can then grab another `NodeCollection` of the other advertisements with

```
HtmlNodeCollection butiks2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class,'butik small left')]");
```

I have some HtmlAgilityPack web scraping code at home, that I can shoot your way they may help as well.

Edit:
You can join the two lists with LINQ

```
butiks.Union(butiks2);
```

Comment: Thank You for answer. Can i join both `NodeCollection`  (`butik-large-image` and `butik small left`)? How to?